# CSS Invalid Property Value

Tags: html, css

I don't understand what's wrong with this? Google Chrome give this "CSS Invalid Property Value".

```
 <h2 class="grid-100" style="font: 'ralewaybold' 35px !important"><span>Portee</span> Goods</h2>
```

How to fix its?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your Font Shorthand property is not valid

The font **CSS** property is either a **shorthand** property for setting `font-style`, `font-variant`, `font-weight`, `font-size`, `line-height` and `font-family`, or a way to set the `element's` `font` to a system font, using **specific** **keywords**.

**Syntax**

```
 h2{
      font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;
    }
```

**In Use**

```
h2{
  font: italic small-caps normal 13px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

**[More about the shorthand font perperty](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/font-shorthand/)**

or used to this

**/* size | family */**

```
font: 2em "Open Sans", sans-serif;
```

**/* style | size | family */**

```
font: italic 2em "Open Sans", sans-serif;
```

**/* style | variant | weight | size/line-height | family */**

```
font: italic small-caps bolder 16px/3 cursive;
```

**/* The font used in system dialogs */**

```
font: message-box;
```

**/* Global values */**

```
font: inherit;
font: initial;
font: unset;
```

Answer (score 3):

Swap the order.  The order of the shorthand matters.

```
<h2 class="grid-100" style="font: 35px 'ralewaybold' !important;">
```

Answer (score 2):

please try this one:

please Add in it:`font-size:35px !important;`

```
<h2 class="grid-100" style="font: ralewaybold; font-size:35px !important;"><span>Portee</span> Goods</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `35px Important` and add it in `font-size: 35px !important`

```
 <h2 class="grid-100" style="font: 'ralewaybold'; font-size: 35px !important"><span>Portee</span> Goods</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed the `;` at the last..

**Your HTML**

```
<h2 class="grid-100" style="font: 'ralewaybold' 35px !important"><span>Portee</span> Goods</h2>
```

**Updated HTML**

```
<h2 class="grid-100" style="font: ralewaybold 35px !important;"><span>Portee</span> Goods</h2>
```